# Find and replace large quantities of text, only specific parts however

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, dos

I would try an explain what I'm trying to accomplish, but it would be better explained by an example.

I'm trying to change something like this:

```
Example Line 1
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Sub line Z
Example Line 2
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Sub line Z
Example Line 3
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Sub line Z
```

And insert lines like so:

```
Example Line 1
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Sub line Z
Example Line 2
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Inserted line 1
-Inserted line 2
-Inserted line 3
-Sub line Z
Example Line 3
-Sub line X
-Sub line Y
-Sub line Z
```

So while the sub-lines may be identical to other example lines, the example lines will always be different.
I was wondering if there is a way to find the specific Example Line (in this case `Example Line 2`) and then find `Sub line Y` inside it, and *then* insert the code afterwards (or before)?

Or is there a completely different logic that I am missing

FYI - using native MS-DOS to create this batch script.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set section=Example line 2
set line=-Sub line Y

rem Search for "line" line *after* "section" line
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%section%" /C:"%line%" theFile.txt') do (
   if not defined StartSection (
      if "%%b" equ "%section%" set StartSection=%%a
   ) else (
      if not defined TargetLine (
         if "%%b" equ "%line%" set TargetLine=%%a& goto continue
      )
   )
)
echo Target line "%line%" into section "%section%" not found
goto :EOF

:continue

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" theFile.txt') do (
   echo(%%b
   if %%a equ %TargetLine% (
      echo -Inserted line 1
      echo -Inserted line 2
      echo -Inserted line 3
   )
)
```

Comment: Geeze, this makes a boatload of sense when I see it in front of me lol.

Comment: I am having a find and replace problem. If you could take a gander, it'd be much appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039591/how-to-format-find-replace-variables-inside-for-loop

Comment: @TurdPile: See my answer in that question

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the text is in a file.

If you want the inserted lines to be spelled out in the command:

```
sed '/Example Line 2/,/Example Line 3/{/-Sub line Z/i\
-Inserted line 1\
-Inserted line 2\
-Inserted line 3
;}' filename
```

If you want to read the inserted lines from a file (e.g. "newfile"):

```
sed '/Example Line 2/,/Example Line 3/{/-Sub line Y/ r newfile
}' filename
```

Comment: I'm using native Windows batch - therefore no `sed`