# How to format find-replace variables inside for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set SECTION=dispid 3
set TARGET=pushscope
@echo on
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%SECTION%" /C:"%TARGET%" %CHECKER%') do (
    if not defined StartSection (
        if not %%b==%%b:%SECTION%=% set StartSection=%%a
    ) else (
    goto :EOF
        if not defined TargetLine (
            goto :EOF :: Do nothing yet
            if not %%b equ !%%b:%TARGET%=! set TargetLine=%%a& goto checkercont
        )
    )
)
```

In StartSection (the problem area), I'm trying to do a find and replace to confirm that this line is the one I desire, and save that line number.

How do I write it so that it will parse the variables correctly and do the find and replace properly?

What I've tried. "[%b]" means the replaced %%b:

```
%%b:%SECTION%=% returns "[%b]:dispid 3=a" (Yes, it somehow gives me an 'a').
!%b:%SECTION%=! returns "!SECTIONa"
!%%b:%SECTION%=! returns "![%b]:dispid 3=!" (which then gives me an error saying 3 is not a command)
!%b:%SECTION%=%! returns "!SECTION!"
!%%b:!SECTION!=! returns "![%b]:!SECTION!=!"
%b:%%SECTION%%=% return "dispid 3" (and error)
```

I feel like for the last one that it parses the bold then the italics. **%b:%**%SECTION%**%=%**
And using ! never seems to accomplish anything except display at least one back to me.

And yes, after a little bit I just started throwing random crap in there (got frustrated).

So what's the proper way to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: `else (goto :EOF  if not defined...)` Are you sure?

Comment: it was there for debugging, you can ignore it - its a large batch file, so skipping to the end gave me results quicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest type of question to answer on SO is the `"This doesn't work - how do I fix it?"` question - where the only clue to what is required is a construct that the OP admits isn't working... Divining quite what is required quite wears out the ol' crystal ball - and repair costs nowadays really eats into the bats' wings and lizards' tongues budget...

I really can't figure out what the obsession with double-inversion is all about, either. Why `if not condition thingtwo else thingone` ?? What's wrong with `if condition thingone else thingtwo`? Maybe I'm just old-fashioned - but perhaps it's politically incorrect or dicriminatory in some absurd way.

So - in the case under examination, assuming the desired result is to determine the linenumber of the first `dispid 3` and that of the line containing `pushscope` that appears after the `dispid 3` in the file `%checker%` (of which no sample is provided...)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set SECTION=dispid 3
set TARGET=pushscope
SET checker=sourcefile.txt
SET startsection=
SET targetline=
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%SECTION%" /C:"%TARGET%" %CHECKER%') do (
 IF DEFINED startsection (
  IF NOT DEFINED targetline (
    ECHO %%b|FIND "%target%">NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET targetline=%%a
  )
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO %%b|FIND "%section%">NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET startsection=%%a
 )
)

ECHO startsection=%startsection% targetline=%targetline%

GOTO :EOF
```

Which worked for me. YMMV.

Comment: I am not understanding your first paragraph. I did not just give my script and say fix it. I stated where the problem was, what I was trying to accomplish with said line, and solutions I've tried. If you wanted to rewrite the code, that was your prerogative.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%SECTION%" "%CHECKER%"') do if not DEFINED StartSection set "StartSection=%%a"
IF NOT DEFINED StartSection (ECHO StartSection %section% NOT found&goto:eof)
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('MORE +%StartSection% "%CHECKER%" ^|findstr /N /C:"%TARGET%"') do if not DEFINED TargetLine set "TargetLine=%%a"
ECHO StartSection at line #%StartSection%
IF NOT DEFINED TargetLine (ECHO TargetLine %target% NOT found) ELSE ECHO TargetLine at line #%TargetLine%
```

Comment: Just by looking, this won't work. Reason being is that StartSection will be set on line 1, and then TargetLine will simply become line 2. Always. Hence I was doing a find-replace to make sure StartSection was the string i wanted. From there the next occurrence of TARGET would be the the desired line. The way I have it works fine - just need to figure out the find-replace part.

Comment: The code assumes, `Section`  comes before `Target` and there is no additional `Section` string between the first and `Target` .

Comment: sorry, not sure what i was thinking about line 1 thing blah blah. But TARGET appears multiple times prior to SECTION. Thefere, StartSection will be set to the TARGET rather than the section. (notice the two parameters in the search). Hence the need to verify the line contains SECTION before setting the StartSection.

Comment: and just to clarify, your script assumes that section will always come before target, however, there are hundreds occurences of target, yet only 1 occurance of section. Hence the need to find section, then the target afterwards - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. I think I don't understand what you tried to achieve with this line:

```
if not %%b==%%b:%SECTION%=% set StartSection=%%a
```

You must realize that `%%b` contains a *line* read from the file, NOT a variable! Let's analyze a little this example:

```
!%%b:%SECTION%=!
```

If `%%b` would contain *the name of a variable*, then the previous line would eliminate the value of `SECTION` from it. However, `%%b` does NOT contain the name of a variable, but a *line* read from a file!

If you want to check if the line read from a file contain the string given by SECTION, then you should do that this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set SECTION=dispid 3
set TARGET=pushscope
@echo on
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%SECTION%" /C:"%TARGET%" %CHECKER%') do (
    if not defined StartSection (
        set "line=%%b"
        if not "!line!" == "!line:%SECTION%=!" set StartSection=%%a
    ) else (
. . .
```